# jQuery 1.7.1 height() stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, migration

I have used `jQuery 1.6.2` so I can get `<div id="drag-container">` width and height and it was working fine

But when I changed to `jQuery 1.7.1` I start to have a problem with `IE (9.0)`

in `$(document).ready()` function

`$("#drag-container").height()` returns 0

and the web page stops it's initial rendering for a 5 seconds.

In fact page is almost fully rendered except (may be) the same `<div id="drag-container">`

Can this be my fault?

I'm also using `HTML5 Boilerplate` and `Twitter Bootstrap with Less`

Comment: Can you give a snippet of your code ?

Comment: I will upload a version so you can test

Comment: if there are images in the `#drag-container` you should use the `$(document).load()` and not the `.ready()` ..

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: You solution is right :) Thank you very much! Can you write it as an answer? And isn't it $(window).load? And why it was working with 1.6.2?

Comment: @ju. posted answer.. It should not make a difference between these versions. except perhaps the first time, due to caching of the jquery library.. or perhaps cached images.. Did you move the location of your code from the end of the page to the top or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are images in the `#drag-container` element, then you should use the [`$(window).load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (***as you rightly corrected in the comment***) instead of the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

That is because the `ready` event is fired once the DOM is ready to be manipulated (*the actual html*) while the `load` event is fired once all assets of the page have been loaded (*including images etc*).

So your code will be running before the images are loaded, and thus their container will not have acquired its height (*which might depend on its content - the images..*)